# Flask, Blueprint Collisions and Pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am using Flask Blueprints to create an application. I am testing it with pytest. Generating `test_client` in different states with `pytest.fixture` is causing a blueprint name collision.

This is my Flask `__init__` code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_user import UserManager
from flask_googlemaps import GoogleMaps
import os
from app.settings import app, db

# get extensions
dropzone = Dropzone()
google_maps = GoogleMaps()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class=Config):

    # initialise extensions
    google_maps.init_app(app)
    dropzone.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    # FLASK-User Stuff
    from app.models import User
    user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    return app
```

I am then trying to use multiple pytests to test different aspects of the application. For each I am creating a `pytest.fixture` to generate a `test_client`. For example I'm creating two fixtures for testing the app with the db in different states.

For example.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client_state1():
    app = create_app()
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://' + PATH_TO_DB_STATE_1
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = app.test_client()
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield client

    ctx.pop()

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client_state2():
    app = create_app()
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://' + PATH_TO_DB_STATE_2
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = app.test_client()
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield client

    ctx.pop()


def test_with_state1(client_state1):
"""Test should pass"""
assert 1 == 1

def test_with_state2(client_state2):
"""Test should pass"""
assert 1 == 1
```

When I run the tests I get the following error.

```
AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x1a16b5d4e0> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x1a1633f6a0>.  Both share the same name "googlemaps".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.
```

I have tried splitting out tests into separate files and setting the scope of the fixture to function. But to no avail. In all cases the first test passes and the second causes the collision. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think, you shouldn't use the same app 'from app.settings import app', make the app unique par create it in each fixture.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I made this change and I was able to resolve the problem.